# Closing form5 from form1 if download completed

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is the whole code from `form1` :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;

namespace BSCS_Launcher
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private WebClient webClient = null;
        const string basPath = @"cstrike";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form6 f6 = new Form6();
            f6.ShowDialog(); // Shows Form6 - Launchoptions
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = @"steamlop.lop";
            string cfgpath = @"cstrike/config.cfg";
            FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(cfgpath);

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.SetAttributes(cfgpath, File.GetAttributes(cfgpath) | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
                var str = File.ReadAllText(path);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("hl.exe", arguments: str);
            }
            else
            {
                string message = "Launch options not found. Please go into launch options and click double click Reset!!!";
                string title = "Launch options error";
                MessageBox.Show(message, title);
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog(); // Shows Form2 - Features
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.ShowDialog(); // Shows Form3 - Options
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://fastxhoster.com/");
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form5 f5 = new Form5();
            f5.ShowDialog(); // Shows Form5 - Updatelauncher

            // Is file downloading yet?
            if (webClient != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var dirdir = new DirectoryInfo($"{basPath}");
            if (!dirdir.Exists)
            {
                webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += FileDownloading;
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://sipi-portfolio.000webhostapp.com/verzija.php"), $"{basPath}/version.php");
            }
            else
            {
                webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += FileDownloading;
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://sipi-portfolio.000webhostapp.com/verzija.php"), $"{basPath}/version.php");
            }  //Ovaj kod treba da se izvrsi tek kada je igracu skinut novi update ukoliko ga je bilo
        }

        private void FileDownloading(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webClient = null;

            string pathfile = $"{basPath}/verzija.php";
            string pathfile2 = $"{basPath}/version.php";
            var str = File.ReadAllText(pathfile);
            var str2 = File.ReadAllText(pathfile2);

            if (str != str2)
            {
                CloseProcessing();
                string message = "We found an avilable update for this launcher!";
                string title = "Update launcher";
                MessageBox.Show(message, title);
            }
            else
            {
                CloseProcessing();
                string message = "No new updates!";
                string title = "Update launcher";
                MessageBox.Show(message, title);
            }
        }

        public void CloseProcessing()
        {
            Form5 f5 = new Form5();
            f5.Close(); // Closes Form5 - Updatelauncher
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see that I created code for download one file from one website, and it should check if those 2 files have the same context, if not it should do something and if yes it should do something again, in both situations, it should close form5, but it not closing... I tried many codes to resolve this but it not affects...

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: What is the use of Form5, here? Is it meant for User *entertainment*? If you need a modal dialog, as a simple solution, you could move that code to Form5, so you don't block the download process (btw, you should declare Form5 - and the other modal Forms  - with a `using` statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just Declare Form5 outside of methods (in the class) and for closing it don't rredefine it:

```
        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form5 f5 = new Form5();
            f5.ShowDialog(); // Shows Form5 - Updatelauncher
```

to

```
        Form5 f5 = new Form5();
        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            f5.ShowDialog(); // Shows Form5 - Updatelauncher
```

and

```
        public void CloseProcessing()
        {
            //remove this line: //Form5 f5 = new Form5();
            f5.Close(); // Closes Form5 - Updatelauncher
        }
```

when you call `Form5 f5 = new Form5();` in `CloseProcessing` you create a new instance of form5 instead of closing existing one.

Comment: I fixed it, i mean, i moved code for download in form 5 and say if download completed close form :D :D, thanks you anyway !!